# What is the governance of the US Government's Project Open Data?

Tags: usa, data.gov, git

The US Government just launched [Project Open Data on GitHub](http://project-open-data.github.io/), which includes best practices, free tools to accelerate adoption of open data practices, and common core metadata for the federal government. What is the planned governance of this effort? Can anyone modify these?

Answer (score 3):

From the [FAQ](http://project-open-data.github.io/faq/) (emphasis is mine):

> **Who can participate in Project Open Data?**
>
> Anyone – Federal employees, contractors, developers, the general
>   public – can view and contribute to Project Open Data.

It is possible to modify the content of the website as well as to contribute to the various tools offered on github by forking the projects. If your pushed changes are approved, they are integrated in the "official" app.

As for the governance, later on in the FAQ:

> **Who is in charge of Project Open Data?**
>
> Ultimately? You. While the
>   White House founded and continues to oversee the project, Project Open
>   Data is a collaborative work — commonly known as “open source” — and
>   is supported by the efforts of an entire community. See the “how to
>   contribute” section above to learn more.
>
> At the onset, the General Services Administration is here to provide
>   daily oversight and support, but over time, it is our vision that
>   contributors both inside and outside of > government can be empowered
>   to take on additional leadership roles.

Comment: As of this comment "daily oversight and support" seems rather optimistic considering none of the 19 pull requests have been accepted (nor commented on). I opened up this issue for more information: https://github.com/project-open-data/project-open-data.github.io/issues/30

Answer (score 0):

There is also a '[Governance](http://project-open-data.github.io/governance)' section on Project Open Data.

*(Disclaimer - I am the Sr. API Strategist for GSA)*